# Rhythmbox opens out of focus from Sound Menu

Tags: 11.04, rhythmbox, indicator-sound

I'm using Ubuntu Natty, though I had noticed this problem in Maverick as well. Because Rhythmbox opens up out of focus, pressing Ctrl-W/Ctrl-Q has the alarming effect of shutting down whatever application was behind Rhythmbox; in my case, generally Firefox. Since nobody else seems to be experiencing this problem, could it be a problem my end?

Answer (score 3):

Don't worry, it's not just you. :)

The same problem was [reported as a Banshee bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=648953) as well, but it was closed because this is actually a [bug with Compiz](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/773428). If you have a Launchpad account, you may want to click the "this affects me too" link and mention that Rhythmbox is also affected by this when it is opened from the sound menu.